# sparkcode to connect hive with kerberos keytab

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kerberos

I am trying to connect to Hive using kerberos keytab authentication using spark 2.4.5
Till now i have developed the below code and i want to convert the same to a dataframe.
How can i do that and is there any other approach to connect to Hive with kerberos keytab apart from this?

```
  val conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krbloc)
  conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
  conf.set("hadoop.security.authorization", "true")
  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hive@drek-test.COM",
    keytab_path)
  Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")

  val con = DriverManager.getConnection(url3)
  con.prepareStatement("select * from table").executeQuery
```

Comment: Why try to re-invent the wheel? Your code will work only in _local_ execution mode; as soon as you have executors running in their own JVM, you are toast.

Comment: Do you know why Spark was invented? To improve the way Hadoop/Hive processed their data files. Spark has native integration with kerberized Hadoop clusters. Spark accesses Hive tables at the filesystem level, without messing with HS2. And that native integration includes management of Hadoop delegation tokens for all executors, after the initial Kerberos auth.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: My requirement is such that i have to access third party cluster outside of my environment and read tables. The hive instance is kerberised so I had to use JDBC for it.Are you telling for this I dont need this type of code and spark can access directly?

Comment: _"The hive instance is kerberised so I had to use JDBC for it."_ > can you back your claim? Details matter.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Please let me the detail you require. I will provide it. Please let me know your questions or details

Comment: Can you reach HDFS _(on all nodes)_ and Hive Metastore _(on 1 node, or on multiple nodes via a ZooKeeper directory)_ from Spark? If yes, just use the built-in support for Hive. If no (e.g. you must go thru the bloody Knox proxy) then good luck using JDBC. But with Knox you would have LDAP authentication and Kerberos would be avoidable.